# Most binaries compiled for Qt 5.3.2 are built without debugging info

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dsymutil

I'm trying to build release version of Qt 5.3.2 with debugging info which I later dump using dsymutil.

Here is the configuration summary used to build Qt:

```
Configure summary

Build type:    macx-clang (x86_64, CPU features: cx16 mmx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3)

qmake vars .......... QMAKE_CC = /usr/bin/cc QMAKE_CXX = /usr/bin/c++ QMAKE_CFLAGS = -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -I/usr/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -mssse3 -gdwarf-4 -fslp-vectorize -fvectorize QMAKE_LFLAGS = -L/usr/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 styles += mac fusion windows DEFINES += QT_NO_MTDEV QMAKE_CFLAGS_FONTCONFIG = -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2  QMAKE_LIBS_FONTCONFIG = -L/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/lib -lfontconfig -lfreetype  DEFINES += QT_NO_LIBUDEV DEFINES += QT_NO_EVDEV INCLUDEPATH +=  "/usr/include" LIBS +=  -L"/usr/lib" sql-drivers =  sql-plugins =  sqlite qmake switches ......... 

Build options:
  Configuration .......... absolute_library_soname accessibility audio-backend concurrent corewlan fontconfig force_debug_info full-config getaddrinfo getifaddrs harfbuzz iconv ipv6ifname large-config largefile medium-config minimal-config opengl openssl-linked pcre png precompile_header qpa qpa qt_framework reduce_exports release rpath shared small-config sse2 sse3 ssse3 system-freetype system-jpeg system-png system-zlib 
  Build parts ............ libs tools examples
  Mode ................... release (with debug info)
  Using C++11 ............ no
  Using PCH .............. yes
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE2/SSE3/SSSE3 ...... yes/yes/yes
    SSE4.1/SSE4.2 ........ no/no
    AVX/AVX2 ............. no/no

Qt modules and options:
  Qt D-Bus ............... no
  Qt Concurrent .......... yes
  Qt GUI ................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............. yes
  Large File ............. yes
  QML debugging .......... yes
  Use system proxies ..... no

Support enabled for:
  Accessibility .......... yes
  ALSA ................... no
  CUPS ................... no
  Evdev .................. no
  FontConfig ............. yes
  FreeType ............... yes (system library)
  Glib ................... no
  GTK theme .............. no
  HarfBuzz ............... yes
  Iconv .................. yes
  ICU .................... no
  Image formats: 
    GIF .................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using system library)
    PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using system library)
  journald ............... no
  mtdev .................. no
  Networking: 
    CoreWlan ............. yes
    getaddrinfo .......... yes
    getifaddrs ........... yes
    IPv6 ifname .......... yes
    OpenSSL .............. yes (linked to the libraries)
  NIS .................... no
  OpenGL / OpenVG: 
    EGL .................. no
    OpenGL ............... desktop
    OpenVG ............... no
  PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)
  pkg-config ............. yes 
  PulseAudio ............. no
  QPA backends: 
    DirectFB ............. no
    EGLFS ................ no
    KMS .................. no
    LinuxFB .............. no
    XCB .................. no
  Session management ..... yes
  SQL drivers: 
    DB2 .................. no
    InterBase ............ no
    MySQL ................ no
    OCI .................. no
    ODBC ................. no
    PostgreSQL ........... no
    SQLite 2 ............. no
    SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    TDS .................. no
  udev ................... no
  xkbcommon .............. no
  zlib ................... yes (system library)
```

However most built binaries lacks debugging info, i.e. dsymutil says there is no debug symbols. Except 2 frameworks: QtCore.framework and QtGui.framework.

I use the `dsymutil -o` command to dump debugging info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding the `-no-strip` flag to configure.